# What algorithm(s) are used by MoleculeModify's GenerateConformers?

Tags: implementation-details, chemistry

Starting with Mathematica 12, the [`MoleculeModify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MoleculeModify.html) function has a `"GenerateConformers"` option.

What is the algorithm used to perform the conformer generation?

Results can vary for [different software packages and algorithm choices](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acs.jcim.7b00505), so knowing the specific algorithm used is one step towards replicability by others.  ([Some of the underlying `Molecule` calculations make use of RDKit functions](https://sourceforge.net/p/rdkit/mailman/message/36188280/); knowing that this is being used here would be sufficient, as the conformer generation algorithm implemented in RDKit does pretty well.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The primary method for conformer generation used by `Molecule` and related functions is the ETKDG method described in ["Better Informed Distance Geometry: Using What We Know To Improve Conformation Generation"](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jcim.5b00654). Versions 12 and 12.1 of the Wolfram Language use versions 1 and 2 of the ETKDG method, respectively.