# Are atom coordinates in Molecules the real equilibrium positions or simple heuristic guesses?

Tags: chemistry

If I do, for example,

`Export["~/Downloads/tnt.xyz", Molecule["TNT"]]`

I get a nice set of coordinates for atoms within a molecule of the explosive TNT.

I don't know where these coordinates actually come from.

They could just be simple guesses based on the typical bond lengths and angles of these elements.

Or, it could be the actual coordinates determined in some experiment.

I'm especially curious to know, if I want to run further analysis on this molecule, do I need to do a geometry optimization, or are the atoms already in their equilibrium positions?

Comment: Most likely the coordinates would have been calculated from an electronic structure calculation with DFT codes. In these calculations the structure of the molecule is relaxed by minimising the total energy.

Comment: You can use https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov. They not only provide the data, but also quote sources.

Comment: The `Molecule[]` framework internally uses [RDKit](https://www.rdkit.org/) and its various algorithms like [ETKDG](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jcim.5b00654) for generating coordinates for a molecule, after which the [MMFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merck_molecular_force_field) energy of the initially generated coordinates is accordingly minimized.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/221442/9490).  In general, if you don't provide coordinates (via `mol = Molecule[atoms, bonds, AtomCoordinates -> listOfCoordinates]` or `mol = Import["myfile.xyz"])` then they are generated as needed using heuristic methods.